# How to update a userform that is a progress bar?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm trying to update my userform `Updating` (which is essentially a progress bar).

It doesn't update the first time the userform is called and the second time it only updates the label description and not the width of the bar.

```
Sub UpdateUpdatingUF(filenum As Integer, filecount As Integer)
    Dim filenumdbl As Double
    Dim filecountdbl As Double
    Dim boxwidth As Integer
    Dim barwidth As Integer
    Dim boxwidthdbl As Double
    filenumdbl = CDbl(filenum)
    filecountdbl = CDbl(filecount)
    boxwidthdbl = CDbl(boxwidth)
    boxwidth = 300
    barwidth = CInt(boxwidthdbl * filenumdbl / filecountdbl)
    With Updating
        .Label3.Caption = "Running file: " & CStr(filenum) & " / " & CStr(filecount)
        .ProgressBar.Width = barwidth
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm probably declaring too many variables but I am trying to make sure that that isn't the cause.

I'm testing with the procedure below.

```
Sub TestUpdate()
    Updating.Show
    Call UpdateUpdatingUF(3, 7)
    DoEvents
    Updating.Repaint
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
Updating.Show
```

with

```
Updating.Show vbModeless
```

Comment: You mean `Updating.Show VbModeless` or `Updating.Show (False)`? You may want to add an explanation on why one needs to do that :)

Comment: i get error 446 - "object doesn't support named arguments"

Comment: `updating.show vbmodeless` works to make the text change but the bar does not change

Comment: this worked if I redrew the progress  bar. Not entirely sure why it worked but it did.

Answer (score 0):

Too late but:

> `boxwidthdbl = CDbl(boxwidth)
>      boxwidth = 300`

those two lines should be in the reverse order :

```
boxwidth = 300
boxwidthdbl = CDbl(boxwidth)
```

as you are using a variable that has not been initialised.

The proposed solution is correct if you want to update during another operation (inside a do/while or a for/next loop for instance). `vbModeless` instructs the program not to wait for the form to be closed. Updating while the form is displayed is made thanks to that and the `DoEvents` instruction.

If the update is only required once, you should also reverse the updating of the values and the display of the form:

```
Call UpdateUpdatingUF(3, 7)
Updating.Show
```

--> this is why you had to test twice to see the results (you displayed the form before updating the values and had to close it to update the values).

Like this, no more need for doevents and repaint.

To be sure to unload the form, if needed for tests purpose, use`Unload Updating`.